# UITableView related method not running

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, methods

my MasterViewController.h is as follows:

```
@interface XYZMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *array; //unimportant
    NSUInteger buttonIndex; //unimportant
    BOOL waitForAction; //unimportant
    NSString *titleEntered;//unimportant
    NSString *duedateEntered; //unimportant
}
```

and in my (.m) file I declared the method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)actionforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"canPerformAction Method entered");
    [self switchTitle:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    return YES;
}
```

but its not running at all, the NSLog never prints out. It's as tho it hets ignored and just continues with the rest of the app.

Thanks 4 any help!

Comment: You need to set the delegate on your table view to point to the controller instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, do you explicitly call your function from somewhere or have you written a custom UITableViewDelegate for it? If neither, no wonder it doesn't get invoked.

I think the function you're looking for is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

And don't forget to set your class as the table's delegate and implement the other delegate functions.